# Know if an Android is downloading (torrent, spotify, soundcloud, etc)

Tags: android

I'm programming an app which disable sometimes data (&wifi). But i don't want to do that if the user is using "streaming apps" (f. ex : soundcloud, spotify, deezer, etc).

I suppose I have to check bandwidth, and so i looked for TrafficStats (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html). But it doesn't for me because i just want to know if at time t, the device is connected and downloading something.

Like that : if (!isUserStreaming()) disableData();

An other possibility would be to check if a "streaming app" is launched and used. For example, determine if Soundcloud is launched and playing some music but I have no idea of how to do that. I suppose i have to check if the background service is running.

Anyway, do you have ideas to help me with that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you can get list of running processes. But you need full list of streaming apps then.

Comment: Yes but the problem with that is even if Soundcloud is running for example, the user is not automatically listening to music on the internet...

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji the process will be running unless explicitly killed by the user, regardless of whether anything is streaming